# Terraform remote_exec that runs kubectl fails?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v1.2.0

I have a generic module that just copies a passed in YAML file name, where that file exists in the same directory as the module, copies it onto the `/tmp` directory on the remote node, and then executes `kubectl apply -f <yaml file>`. `kubectl` is installed on the node; I can run the command manually on the node.

```yaml
// Copy local file to remote location
resource "null_resource" "copy_script" {
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file(var.ssh_key_file)
    host        = var.ec2_pub_ip
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "../modules/nginx/${var.conf_file}"
    destination = "/tmp/${var.conf_file}"
  }
}

// Run kubectl apply on the passed-in YAML
// configuration file.
resource "null_resource" "kubectl_apply" {
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file(var.ssh_key_file)
    host        = var.ec2_pub_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo kubectl apply -f /tmp/${var.conf_file}"
    ]
  }
}
```

I call the above module this way

```yaml
// Install nginx deployment
module "k8s_install_nginx_deploy" {
  source                 = "../modules/nginx"
  ssh_key_file           = var.ssh_key_file
  ec2_pub_ip             = module.k8s_ec2_master_0.ec2_pub_ip
  conf_file              = "nginx-deployment.yaml"
}
// Install nginx service
module "k8s_install_nginx_svc" {
  source                 = "../modules/nginx"
  ssh_key_file           = var.ssh_key_file
  ec2_pub_ip             = module.k8s_ec2_master_0.ec2_pub_ip
  conf_file              = "nginx-service.yaml"
}
```

However Terraform gives me

```
╷
│ Error: remote-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with module.k8s_install_nginx_svc.null_resource.kubectl_apply,
│   on ../modules/nginx/main.tf line 24, in resource "null_resource" "kubectl_apply":
│   24:   provisioner "remote-exec" {
│ 
│ error executing "/tmp/terraform_738306599.sh": Process exited with status 1
╵
```

I used the same technique running shell scripts, that is, the provisioner just runs a `"sudo /tmp/${var.shell_script}"` and it works.

What am I missing? TIA

Comment: You are trying a `kubectl apply` on a shell script? Is that really what you want?

Comment: No, `kubectl apply -f some.yaml`. I just mentioned that I used a similar module, not the same module, to run shel scripts.

Comment: The error shows you were trying to apply a shell script: `"/tmp/terraform_738306599.sh"`. :)

Comment: @MarkoE, the way I understand it, terraform converts the provisioner into a shell script on the remote node, and then runs that shell script. The file `/tmp/terraform_738306599.sh` is created by Terraform.

Comment: Well, this is the line in the `remote-exec` provisioner: `"sudo kubectl apply -f /tmp/${var.conf_file}"`. So to me it seems you told it to run whatever is under `/tmp/${var.conf_file}`. That seems to be the same file you are copying over to the EC2 instance in the `copy_script` `null_resource`.

Comment: @MarkoE, correct. `/tmp/${var.conf_file}` is NOT `/tmp/terraform_738306599.sh`. I'll update the calling script to make it clear. Thanks.